# Method is executed without calling it?

Tags: ruby, method-call

I came across this solution for a Proxy class in [the Ruby koans](http://www.gembalabs.com/2009/04/14/exploring-the-ruby-koans-building-an-object-proxy/):

```
class Proxy
  attr_accessor :messages

  def initialize(target_object)
    @object = target_object
    @messages = []
  end
  def method_missing(method_name, *args, &block)
    @messages << method_name
    @object.send(method_name, *args, &block)
  end
end
```

I can create an object from this proxy class by passing another class as an argument. For instance, the following code will result in `"Do something"`, without having to type `thing.method_missing(:do_thing)`:

```
class Thing
  def do_thing
    puts "Doing something."
  end
end

thing = Proxy.new(Thing.new)
thing.do_thing
```

Why is the code in `method_missing` executed even without having to call said method?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for `method_missing`? http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/BasicObject.html#method-i-method_missing

Comment: P.S. That's an instance method, not a class method.

Comment: "Invoked by Ruby automatically when obj is sent a message it cannot handle". Yes this is perfect, thanks!

Comment: The Ruby documentation has a section [Method Lookup](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Method+Lookup) which also covers `method_missing`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are methods that are called implicitly (i.e., called even when you don't write it in the code) when a certain event happens or a certain method is called. I call these methods *hooks*, borrowing the terminology of e-lisp. As far as I know, Ruby has the following hooks:

**Ruby hooks**

```
at_exit
set_trace_func
initialize
method_missing
singleton_method_added
singleton_method_removed
singleton_method_undefined
respond_to_missing?
extended
included
method_added
method_removed
method_undefined
const_missing
inherited
initialize_copy
initialize_clone
initialize_dup
prepend
append_features
extend_features
prepend_features
```

And `method_missing` is one of them. For this particular one, it is automatically called when Ruby cannot find a defined method. Or in other words, `method_missing` is the most default method that is called with the least priority, for any method call.

Answer (score 1):

`method_missing` is one of the amazing aspects of `metaprogramming` in ruby. With proper use of this method, you can gracefully handle exceptions and whatnot. In your case it is called because the method you are calling on the object doesn't exist obviously.

But one should be careful of its use too. While you are at it do look at `responds_to` method too.

An example regarding `ActiveRecord` will make you understand better. When we write:

```
User.find_by_email_and_age('me@example.com', 20)
```

There isn't actually a method by that name. This call goes to the `method_missing` and then this fancy`find`method is broken down into pieces and you are served what you asked for. I hope that helps.

Comment: Another consideration: `method_missing` can be a bear to debug, with  `"SystemStackError: stack level too deep"` being a constant refrain.